# Sorting an array using probability percentages in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am creating a genetic calculator using Laravel 5.6 in which a species' genetic "morphs" and the relevant info are pulled from the database to complete the calculation. I pass the morph data in an array along with the precent chance (represented with a decimal) that the offspring will inherit one or two copies of the gene. The goal is to output a list of possible combinations, but I'm not sure of such a feature exists in PHP.

Example array dump:

[image: Example array]

The array consists of each gene passed from the parent data (`Pastel` and `Spider` in this case) and contains the Eloquent model for the morph and the chance the gene will be present with one or two copies. What this would break down to in practice is the following:

- 25% Pastel (2/2 copies) Spider
- 25% Pastel (2/2)
- 25% Pastel (1/2) Spider
- 25% Pastel (1/2)

It breaks down this way because there is a 50% of each "copy" of the gene being passed on according to the array data, with spider only having a 50% chance of showing at all and no chance of showing with two copies.

How can I take the data I have, or data structured similarly, and output a result like the one above? Apologies for wordy explanation, I hope I have adequately explained what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm unsure whether the Example array dump you showed is an example of what you are starting with, or trying to get to. And whichever one it is, can you also provide a code example of the other? The way you've described it makes sense, but I think an example will be helpful to clarify.

Comment: I didn't understand your example. Could you please use different values (0.7-0.3 / 0.4-0.6) to notice the behavior?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you for the response. The array dump is my starting point, and I am trying to use that data to output a result like the list below it. I am essentially looking at the different combinations possible of those two arrays given the decimal chance.